# Is there an easy way to compute a finite number of sequential equal powers in some modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

For example, is there a easy way to compute
$$32^{A_1^{A_2^{\ \cdots^{{}^{A_{32}}}}}} \mod 7$$

whith $A_i=32 \, , \  i=1,\cdots,32$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the sequence of powers of $32$, reduced mod $7$, we get
\begin{align*}
32^0&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
32^1&\equiv 4\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
32^2&\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
32^3&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;7)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the mod $7$ sequence is $1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,...$, repeating in blocks of $3$.

It follows that
$$
{32}^n\;\text{mod}\;7
=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;n\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\
4&\text{if}\;n\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\
2&\text{if}\;n\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Looking at the sequence of powers of $32$, reduced mod $3$, we get
\begin{align*}
32^0&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
32^1&\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
32^2&\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the mod $3$ sequence is $1,2,1,2,1,2,...$, repeating in blocks of $2$.

It follows that
$$
{32}^n\;\text{mod}\;3
=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
2&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, since $A_2$ is even, it follows that the expression starting at the base $A_1$ is congruent to $1$ mod $3$, so the full expression, starting at the base $32$ is congruent to $4$ mod $7$.